# In C#, how can I convert my array from IEnumerable<IMyInterface> to IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, ienumerable

In C#, I want to take an array of Type "T" **where I know "T" supports the interface "IMyInterface**" and:

1. Cast it as array of "IMyinterface"
2. Call a method on that array that will filter the list
3. Cast it back to the original type T list.

1 and 2 above work fine, but I am running into issues on step #3.

Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<IMyInterface> castedArray = originalTypedArray as IEnumerable<IMyInterface>;

if (castedArray != null)
{
    var filteredArray = castedArray.Where(r => r.Ids.Contains(MyId)).ToList();

     IEnumerable<T> castedBackToOriginalTypeArray = filteredArray as IEnumerable<T>;
     if (castedBackToOriginalTypeArray == null)
     {
          current = new List<T>();
     }
     else
     {
        current = castedBackArray;
     }

     // I need to cast back, because only my Type T has the .Id property
     List<int> ids = current.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
 }
```

The issue is on this line:

```
 IEnumerable<T> castedBackToOriginalTypeArray = filteredArray as IEnumerable<T>;
```

That always seem to return null (instead of the filtered array cast back to IEnumerable<T>.

Any suggestions here for what I might be doing wrong and how to correct cast an array of an interface back into an array of type T?

Comment: Does cast from `T` to `IMyInterface` works without IEnumerable?

Comment: Why do you need to cast at all? Can't you filter the original `IEnumerable<MyInterface>` ?

Comment: @LucMorin - I am doing the filter on the IEnumerable<MyInterface> but i need to convert it back to the original type because my next line of code depends on it.. i have updated the question to make that clearer

Comment: @kat1330 - converting to the array of IMyInterface works fine with the code above

Comment: If you leave off the ToList(), filtered array should already be IEnumerable, no need to cast it again.

Comment: I still don't see the need to cast to array. Why don't you call `Where` and `Select` directly on the `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @LucMorin - because the IMyInterface does NOT have the .Id Properly (did you see my updated question?)

Comment: @tinstaafl - removing the ToList() didn't seem to make a difference, i am still always getting null when trying to cast back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class A : IA {

}


public interface IA {

}

List<A> l = new List<A> { new A(), new A(), new A() };
IEnumerable<IA> ias = l.Cast<IA>();
IEnumerable<A> aTypes = ias.Cast<A>();
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate the entire collection to cast each object. This will also crash if the collection contains something which is *not* a `T` (and hence why the `as` conversion returns null)

Comment: @Rob The OP specifically said: `I want to take an array of Type "T" where I know "T" supports the interface "IMyInterface" ` so why would it crash.

Comment: Because potentially the 'filtering' could add something to the collection. There's no type safety here. In fact, a cast isn't actually needed if you can *prove* that only `T` will be contained within the collection.

Comment: Surely using `OfType<T>` "solves" the casting issues. Not only will it return the filtered list as `IEnumerable<T>` but it will also ignore items not of type `T`

Answer (score 0):

Either you don't need to cast it to `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`, or the runtime has correctly prevented you from writing buggy code.

Let's take a smaller example:

```
void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> originalTypedArray, int MyId) 
    where T : class, IMyInterface
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is important 
{
    if (originalTypedArray != null)
    {
        var filteredArray = originalTypedArray.Where(r => r.Ids.Contains(MyId));

        // No need to cast to `IEnumerable<T>` here - we already have ensured covariance
        // is valid in our generic type constraint
        DoSomethingExpectingIEnumerableOfIMyInterface(filteredArray);
    }
}
void DoSomethingExpectingIEnumerableOfIMyInterface(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> src)
{
    foreach (var thing in src)
    {

    }
}
```

However, if you're *not* getting the collection as `IEnumerable<T>`, then the runtime is correctly failing the cast:

```
void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> originalTypedArray, int MyId)
```

We could give it a bunch of `IEnumerable<Apple>` assuming `Apple : IMyInterface`. Then you try to cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` where `T  = Banana` and boom, code broken.